# Where do these faces originate from?

Tags: meme

I've seen these manly faces several places over the internet (especially the one on the right) & I'm pretty sure it's from sort of manga.

Does anyone know where these faces originate?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This originated from [here](http://nijuukoo.tumblr.com/post/39412252025/i-should-not-be-allowed-to-draw-on-balloons). It's based on [this meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/yaranaika-%E3%82%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B), which itself is based on the manga [Kuso Miso Technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuso_Miso_Technique), which was in the manga supplement of the gay magazine Barazoku in 1987. Scanned images of it began circulating the internet in 2002, and it became a meme after that.